# Returning results from ZXing

Tags: zxing

i am trying to embed ZXing into my application in eclipse. the app completes a scan and then the app is force closed for throwing a nullPointerException. in logcat i am told failure returning results.

Answer (score 1):

(In the future you should really write a better question. This has almost no relevant detail. For example, if you see an exception, post the stack trace.)

It is almost surely an error in your `onActivityResult()` handler, judging by the logcat message. Find the NPE and fix it in your code. It is nothing to do with the library.

Answer (score 0):

Update your onActivityResult like this.

```
 //method for getting qr code from qr code after scan
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                    if (requestCode == 0) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    Toast.makeText(this, contents , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

                            // Handle successful scan
                        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                            // Handle cancel
                            Log.d("the result is","not ok");
                        }
                    }
```